# Installing Python's Cryptography on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ssh

I've created a script on windows to connect to Remote SSH server. I have successfully installed `cryptography`, `pynacl` and finally `paramiko`(Took me an entire day to figure out how to successfully install them on windows).

Now that I run the script, it pops an error saying that the DLL loading has failed. The error seems to be related to `libsodium` but I cannot figure out exactly which DLL is to trying to load and from where. Just to be on the safer side I also installed `pysodium`.

Here's the script:

> automate.py

```
import SSH

connection = ssh("10.10.65.100", "gerrit2", "gerrit@123")
print("Calling OpenShell")
connection.openShell()
print("Calling sendShell")
connection.sendShell("ls -l")
print("Calling process")
connection.process()
print("Calling closeConnection")
connection.closeConnection()
```

> SSH.py

```
import threading, paramiko

class ssh:
    shell = None
    client = None
    transport = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        print("Connecting to server on ip", str(address) + ".")
        self.client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((address, 22))
        self.transport.connect(username=username, password=password)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def closeConnection(self):
        if(self.client != None):
            self.client.close()
            self.transport.close()

    def openShell(self):
        self.shell = self.client.invoke_shell()

    def sendShell(self, command):
        if(self.shell):
            self.shell.send(command + "\n")
        else:
            print("Shell not opened.")

    def process(self):
        global connection
        while True:
            # Print data when available
            if self.shell != None and self.shell.recv_ready():
                alldata = self.shell.recv(1024)
                while self.shell.recv_ready():
                    alldata += self.shell.recv(1024)
                strdata = str(alldata, "utf8")
                strdata.replace('\r', '')
                print(strdata, end = "")
                if(strdata.endswith("$ ")):
                    print("\n$ ", end = "")
```

And here's the error:

```
> python automate.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automate.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SSH
  File "D:\Automate\SSH_Paramiko\SSH.py", line 1, in <module>
    import threading, paramiko
  File "D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.4.0-py3.7.egg\paramiko\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.4.0-py3.7.egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 57, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.4.0-py3.7.egg\paramiko\ed25519key.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nacl\signing.py", line 19, in <module>
    import nacl.bindings
  File "D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nacl\bindings\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nacl.bindings.crypto_box import (
  File "D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nacl\bindings\crypto_box.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nacl._sodium import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Seems like *pynacl* is not installed OK. One of its extension modules (or some of its *.dll* dependencies) can't be found. You should be able to reproduce the issue simply by: `import paramiko`. BTW: what's *Python37* in your paths?

Comment: @CristiFati : I did `where python` and received this path `D:\Users\prashant-gu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe`

Comment: @CristiFati: Thanks for the clue that you gave me. It took a lot of effort but finally the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling, I finally stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/issues/281). As mentioned in the conversation I uninstalled my previous pynacl installation, downloaded the zipped source from https://github.com/lmctv/pynacl/archive/v1.2.a0.reorder.zip, downloaded libsodium from https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases/download/1.0.15/libsodium-1.0.15.tar.gz, set `LIB` environment variable to `D:\Users\prashant-gu\Downloads\libsodium-1.0.15\bin\x64\Release\v140\dynamic`, and finally installed pynacl form this downloaded source using

`pip install .`

Now it works fine.

During the installation of `paramiko`, I also happen to download OpenSSL from https://ci.cryptography.io/job/cryptography-support-jobs/job/openssl-release-1.1/, and set INCLUDE environment variable to `D:\Users\prashant-gu\Downloads\openssl-1.1.0g-2015-x86_64\openssl-win64-2015\include` in order to successfully install the `cryptography` package which happens to be a dependency for `paramiko`.